# Matching literal percent in h2/postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I have the following value in a db column:

`some%thing`

I'm using h2 and postgres, but can't figure out why this query, where I have escaped the `%` to perform a literal search, is not matching the row highlighted?:

`LIKE 'some\%thing'`

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `'value'` is a character string literal and not the name of your column. You need to use double quotes instead.

`"value" LIKE 'some\%hing'`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use regular expressions:

```
where value ~ '%'
```

`LIKE` also supports an explicit escape character:

```
where value like '%$%%' escape '$'
```

Or the default one, `\`.